# Importing Multivariate Columns from CSV file to SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to import a csv data sheet into Oracle SQL Developer. One of the columns has numerous values, as my database is an organization with many members.

How do I declare a multivariate column in Oracle SQL?

And how do I insert numerous values into a column with the data source coming from Excel? (I know how to import data from Excel, but just not sure how to insert numerous values separated by commas into SQL Developer)

Example: I want a `memberID` column with numerous values. 
     For ID 5, Member ID (column): "123, 442, 245, 847":

```
ID | memberID
---|---------
5  | 123, 442, 245, 847
```

Please and thank you!

Comment: Hi, just wanted to point out, it would be easier for your question audience if you specified the sql dialect.  I extrapolated it was oracle based on your tool choice of _SQL Developer_.

Comment: Consider having 3 columns; an "ID" column, a "Sub-ID" column and a "Value" column. Then for the example provided, four (4) rows would be used to store the specified values Each with an ID of 5, Sub-IDs of 1-4, then the four values.